# Is windows 10 RDP client a provisioned app?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

We are building a custom image on windows 10 and do not want to include the remote desktop client on it. We found powershell scripts to remove provisioned apps but there RDP client is not in that list.

The RDP client is the windows store app that appears installed in an update and not the 32 bit version in the system32 directory.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The application is in `%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe`.

You could simply remove it.  However, that would not prevent someone from using copying it on, or running a 3rd party RDP tool.  Unless, you lock the machine down from such activities.  If you are trying to prevent people from using RDP, then you are better off disabling the port it uses, TCP port 3389.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the Universal app version, I am aware of this version but need to prevent users from accessing the one that is available on the windows store app which is installed in a windows update.